# How do you get data from a remote MySQL database into your app?

Tags: iphone, titanium

Have just finished a couple of tutorials regarding populating a SQLite database with data and then using this data within your app.
However none of these tutorials show how to connect to a remote server in order to obtain data.

QUESTION:

How do you get data from a remote MySQL database into your app??
What options do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remote access is not a good idea, you would have to allow everyone to access it since it's an app. The best way to go about this is to build a layer between your app and database. From the app you would access a server side script which does the database work and responds to your app.

Comment: Thanks!  Are there examples of this that you could link to, or a resource like a tutorial on this subject that you know about??

Comment: http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json this seems to be presented at the most basic level

Answer (score 2):

Well there are methods to allow remote access to your mysql database on your server and being able to query the database remotely. I think this is the cleanest solution. Check out this link: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html